# Releasing a Chrome tab into its own window, using only the keyboard

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, debian-jessie

**Problem**

I often find that one of the tabs in my Chrome window needs to be moved to another monitor, so I can view it alongside a tab in the current window.

The act of actually moving a window between monitors is not the issue; my OS has hotkeys for that.

**Question**

Is there a way to separate a tab from its window into its own, using only the keyboard? I can, of course, drag the tab out using the mouse, but as you might have guessed, I try to do as much as possible with the keyboard only, for productivity reasons.

I have of course read [Google's support page for chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en), but it only lists it as the mouse-drag operation.

**Additional info**

While I hope the answer would be OS-neutral, I would gladly accept a Debian-only answer. (Jessie, by the way.)

Comment: A quick look on the Ubuntu SE has a couple of extensions for Chrome: http://askubuntu.com/questions/624153/how-can-i-detach-a-tab-from-my-main-chrome-window-into-a-new-window

Comment: @BigChris - Thanks! Works like a charm! That also answers a question I didn't ask; "what's the damn word I'm looking for?!" It was "detach".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in using Chrome extensions then an answer at AskUbuntu (SE) has a couple of suggestions:

1. [Tab To Window](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-to-window-keyboard-sh/adbkphmimfcaeonicpmamfddbbnphikh/related?hl=en-GB) extension
2. [Tab Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-manager/coonecdghnepgiblpccbbihiahajndda?hl=en) extension

Source URL: https://askubuntu.com/questions/624153/how-can-i-detach-a-tab-from-my-main-chrome-window-into-a-new-window